# If A is a matrix, what does A' mean?

Tags: matrices

If A is a matrix, what does A' mean?

I have tried google this but nothing came up.

My new stats course had some review problems, and these multiple choice came up.

Which statement is true?

(a) (AB)' = A'B'

(b) (AB)' = B'A'

(c) Both a and b

(d) Neither a nor b

Which statement is true?

(a) A'' = A

(b) A''' = A'

(c) Both a and b

(d) Neither a nor b

Comment: Where did you see this notation ? Can you tell more in detail ?

Comment: Most likely it means the transposition of the matrix, $\left[A^T\right]_{ij} = \left[A\right]_{ji} $.

Comment: Transpose, not transposition.

Comment: My mistake - you are correct.

Comment: Might be transpose of a matrix

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, it usually means the [matrix transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). This operation is an involutive anti-morphism, which is not the important thing to remember. The important thing is that:

- $A''=A$, where $A''$ means $(A')'$, i.e., the transpose operation applied twice, see [[Involution]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29)
- $(AB)' = B'A'$

Given this, it is not difficult to derive that the correct answers are (b) for the 1st question and (c) for the second one.